# Importing manual gating from FlowJo to R (flow cytometry analysis)

Tags: r, excel

I am experiencing an issue with reading an .xls or .wspt files into R. This is a table of flow cytometry manual gating schema. my code is as follows:

```
   flowData = system.file("extdata",package="flowWorkspace")
   file = list.files(flowData,pattern="manual.xls"/"manual.wspt", full=TRUE)
   ws = openWorkspace(file)
```

When I try to read with openWorkspace, the .xls file gives an error:

```
Start tag expected. "(" not found.
```

I have seen this error in another post, but it doesn't seem to explain my case. 
while, for opening the .wspt file, i receive an error:

```
error in data.frame...arguments imply differing number of rows:1,0.
```

Both of these files (.xls and .wspt) contain the same information. I just wanted to try to read both of them.